# Lua перебор именованных элементов в строке таблицы

Tags: lua

Мне нужно перемешать вопросы и ответы в таблице.
Для перемешивания ответов маркированных последовательностью переменных `a1 a2 a3` и т.д.
мне приходится их перебирать. Поиск последнего элемента делает функция `getacount`.
Наверное можно сделать поиск последнего ответа на вопрос как-то более эстетично, чем у меня.
Или вообще избавится от функция `getacount`.

Помогите сделать код более эффективным.

```
tbl=tbl or {}
table.insert(tbl, {q="Вопрос-1", a1="Ответ-1", a2="Ответ-2", a3="Ответ-3", a4="Ответ-4"})
table.insert(tbl, {q="Вопрос-2", a1="Ответ-1", a2="Ответ-2", a3="Ответ-3"})
table.insert(tbl, {q="Вопрос-3", a1="Ответ-1", a2="Ответ-2"})
table.insert(tbl, {q="Вопрос-4", a1="Ответ-1", a2="Ответ-2", a3="Ответ-3", a4="Ответ-4", a5="Ответ-5"})
table.insert(tbl, {q="Вопрос-5", a1="Ответ-1", a2="Ответ-2", a3="Ответ-3", a4="Ответ-4", a5="Ответ-5", a6="Ответ-6", a7="Ответ-7"})
table.insert(tbl, {q="Вопрос-6", a1="Ответ-1", a2="Ответ-2"})

function getacount(quest)
local tmp
local j = 1
local tmp = "a" .. tostring(j);
    while quest[tmp] do
        j = j + 1
        tmp = "a" .. tostring(j);
    end
j = j - 1
return j
end

function shuffleqAns (arr)
local t = getacount(arr)
  for i = 1, t - 1 do
    local j = math.random(i, t)
    arr["a" .. tostring(i)], arr["a" .. tostring(j)] = arr["a" .. tostring(j)], arr["a" .. tostring(i)]
  end
  return arr
end

function shuffleQ (arr)
  for i = 1, #arr - 1 do
    local j = math.random(i, #arr)
    arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
  end
end

function shuffleA (arr)
  for i = 1, #arr do
    shuffleqAns(arr[i])
  end
end

print("==========================")

for i,n in ipairs(tbl) do
    print(i, n.q)
    print("------------")
    for j = 1, getacount(n) do
        print(n["a" .. tostring(j)])
    end
print("------------")
end

print("==========================")

print("Перемешать ответы и вопросы")

shuffleA(tbl)
shuffleQ(tbl)

print("==========================")

for i,n in ipairs(tbl) do
    print(i, n.q)
    print("------------")
    for j = 1, getacount(n) do
        print(n["a" .. tostring(j)])
    end
    print("------------")
end

print("==========================")
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно переделать индексацию ответов, так будет намного проще:

```
math.randomseed(os.time())

tbl=tbl or {}
table.insert(tbl, {q="Вопрос-1", [1]="Ответ-1", [2]="Ответ-2", [3]="Ответ-3", [4]="Ответ-4"})
table.insert(tbl, {q="Вопрос-2", [1]="Ответ-1", [2]="Ответ-2", [3]="Ответ-3"})
table.insert(tbl, {q="Вопрос-3", [1]="Ответ-1", [2]="Ответ-2"})
table.insert(tbl, {q="Вопрос-4", [1]="Ответ-1", [2]="Ответ-2", [3]="Ответ-3", [4]="Ответ-4", [5]="Ответ-5"})
table.insert(tbl, {q="Вопрос-5", [1]="Ответ-1", [2]="Ответ-2", [3]="Ответ-3", [4]="Ответ-4", [5]="Ответ-5", [6]="Ответ-6", [7]="Ответ-7"})
table.insert(tbl, {q="Вопрос-6", [1]="Ответ-1", [2]="Ответ-2"})


function shuffle(arr)
  for i = 1, #arr - 1 do
    local j = math.random(i, #arr)
    arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
  end
end

function shuffleA (arr)
  for i = 1, #arr do
    shuffle(arr[i])
  end
end

print("==========================")

for i,n in ipairs(tbl) do
    print(i, n.q)
    print("------------")
    for j = 1, #n do
        print(n[j])
    end
print("------------")
end

print("==========================")

print("Перемешать ответы и вопросы")

shuffleA(tbl)
shuffle(tbl)

print("==========================")

for i,n in ipairs(tbl) do
    print(i, n.q)
    print("------------")
    for j = 1, #n do
        print(n[j])
    end
    print("------------")
end
```

еще, перед началом использования random рекомендуется выполнить инициализацию генератора случайных чисел `math.randomseed(os.time())`

Comment: Спасибо, @Mike V. Это отличное решение!